# How to bundle java image with jpackage and moditect to .app file?

Tags: java, macos, jlink, java-14, moditect

I've just created a java application and created an image with moditect-jlink including the JRE. But now I'm wondering how to bundle it up to an .app file for OSX.
Has anyone tried it yet? It seems like jpackage is changing continuously and tutorials are gettin outdated pretty fast.

Comment: “It seems like jpackage is changing continuously and tutorials are gettin outdated pretty fast.”  Yes, relying on beta software is generally has that problem.  Your best bet is to wait until Java 14 is officially released in March.  At that time, its capabilities will be stable.

Comment: (Update: I just saw that jpackage will have incubator status in Java 14, so even in March it may not be completely stable.  Personally I’d wait until it’s out of incubator status.)

Comment: Hi, I have tried to successfully build a DMG file for my application using jpackage together with a pre-built blink-created runtime. I still have a problem with file-associations on macOS though (i. e. to register my app for a file type), and I haven't tried to sign the app yet. jpackage still has some rough edges, but it works. It has also been more or less stable in the last couple of EA builds. If you have a more concrete question, just post it.